# Overall build statistics from Bamboo server

Tags: java, api, continuous-integration, bamboo

I am trying to use Bamboo's remote API to extract some statistics. It looks like it doesn't support extensive reporting. All I got was a way to get the most recent builds. What I need is a list of all builds (maybe up to a numerical limit) or at least the count of successful/failed builds so far, is this available anywhere? any other ideas on how to get this information?

Here is the Bamboo documentation for remote access that I am referencing:

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bamboo+Remote+API

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, the only answer I found to this was to get latest build info, then decrement build number and get the information based on the build number, there is no service that returns a list of builds up to a certain number.